# Error in once functioning C# project - no suitable method found to override

Tags: c#, outlook, project

In short, I'm building an addin for Outlook in `C#` and I've ran into a bit of a panic-situation. Please forgive if some of the information I provided is not relevant to solving my problem, but I cannot diagnose where this issue came from or why.

My problem is as follow:
At an early part of my code, I have...

```
protected override Microsoft.Office.Core.IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
{
    return new Ribbon1();
}
```

The problem is that now, all of a sudden, I get:

> Error 1   'asd.ThisAddIn.CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()': no suitable
>   method found to override

(`asd` is just the namespace I'm using)

Up until now, I was essentially done, and decided to start my construction on another project.

Upon returning to my Outlook addin, I find this and other errors such as:

> Error    2   The name 'Properties' does not exist in the current context

What could possibly have happened?

Like I said, I left this project essentially done, and came back to nothing working.

Please, I'm really desperate here, as I can't see what the problem is.

Comment: Are you missing a reference assembly? If you use source control (if not, why not?!) have you tried going back to a previous commit and seeing if the problem is fixed

Comment: @Sayse I'm pretty sure I'm not missing any assembly. How would I go about checking that? I also don't have any backups of this, as I essentially wrote the entire addin in one long session (I know, horrid idea, but time was tight), so reverting to an old commit is off the table unless VS has this functionality.

Comment: Did you accidentally delete an inheritance clause from the class that contains `CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject`?

Comment: You would have errors normally that indicate something is missing, are all these errors in one file? if so, its possible (amongst other things) that you've added a rogue character (i.e `}`) to the file somewhere that has messed with things everywhere. But please, before even starting to play around with the code more, source control it or make a backup, you won't want to end up in a position where it gets even more messed up

Comment: Does `Microsoft.Office.Tools` namespace come from installing Office or is it part of the .Net Framework? Perhaps you have uninstalled/updated Office? Perhaps you can show the signature of the class in which this code exists?

Comment: @GSerg I'm sorry, but I don't really know what you're asking here. I'm pretty sure I didn't, manually, at least, so unless "Rebuild", or "Clean" or something I could have hit by accident removes such things for me, I am not aware of me having made any such changes.

Comment: Sayse is probably right, the code you quote is *not* the very first line of your code. In all likelihood you introduced a typo breaking your class inheritance. If you post your full code up to the first error we'll probably be able to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @Hughnited - Your edit removed ViRALiC's update... please check you are editing the most up to date version when making an edit

Comment: @Paul-Jan I added my entire class, so that people can see where my quote is coming from, but I honestly can't see my error, even now.

Comment: Where are the other partial classes? This one doesn't inherit from anything. What compiler _warnings_ are there?

Comment: @CodeCaster All my other classes are located straight in the solution itself. There are no sub-directories or anything like that (organization was not a priority when I made this and it may have bitten me in the ass now). I'll update my question with the entire error list.

Comment: I mean where is the other `public partial class ThisAddIn` and what type does it inherit from? Does _that_ file show any errors?

Comment: Yes, @CodeCaster is correct here, you are showing us a `partial` class which means there may be another partial class that does inherit from something else (perhaps `AddInBase`?). If that doesn't exist, then that is your issue.

Comment: @CodeCaster Honestly, I don't really know. Upon creating a new Outlook 2010 addin from the VS menu, it just gives me `public partial class ThisAddIn` from the getgo. How can I find out if I'm missing a `partial` class?

Comment: I don't remember the workflow for addins. There should be a `ThisAddIn.designer.cs` or something, that has `public partial class ThisAddIn : AddInBase`. Set the cursor in your `ThisAddIn` class name and hit F12 or "Go To Definition" . VS will show you all partial classes. If you only find one, you have lost the designer file and are in trouble.

Comment: @CodeCaster Alright, I mouse-over'ed (that's probably not a word) `ThisAddIn` and hit F12 to no result. I then right-clicked `ThisAddIn` and hit "Go To Definition" and nothing happened. So I'm guessing that should have taken me somewhere in a perfect world, huh?

Comment: @CodeCaster I decided to go looking in my directory, and I found a file called "ThisAddIn.Designer.cs". Is that the one you're talking about?

Comment: Yes, you should include that in your project.

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm not sure I understand. I found that file in my addin directory, so how is it not already "in" my project?

Comment: Files that are in your project directory are not included in your project by default. See [How to: Add Existing Items to a Project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx). If "Go To Definition" doesn't show you multiple options (i.e. multiple files declaring that class as partial), the .designer.cs got removed from your project somehow.

Comment: @CodeCaster Clearly not. I did as that article told me, and I chose the correct file, but after having done so, the error persists and I can see my newly added file nowhere in my Solution Explorer. Did it not succeed? Thank you so much for taking the time to help me thus far by the way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87569/discussion-between-viralic-and-codecaster).

Comment: @CodeCaster Just thought I'd let you know, that I stumbled upon some thread, recommending I delete the file in question, having VS re-build it, then re-adding it. And that did the trick. If you can to compile some answer, I will accept it as the correct one, as you were the one who led me to this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, it might not be a very technical answer, but the following is what I did that solved said issue for me:

1. Find `YourClassNameHere.designer.cs` (usually found in the solution directory)
2. Make sure Visual Studio or *YourEditorHere* is completely closed.
3. Delete `YourClassNameHere.designer.cs` from the directory.
4. Reboot (this one might not be as mandatory, but I had to reboot to get it working).
5. Success!

I know it's a bit of a non-technical and flimsy solution to the problem, but it worked for me so hopefully it can work for someone else too.

Answer (score -1):

you have to create your class by inheriting `AddInBase` class as follows.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn : AddInBase
```

without inheriting a class how you can override a method of the base class?

Comment: When I hit "File" > "New" > "Project" and navigate to "Outlook 2010 Add-in" it gives me "public partial class ThisAddIn". This has worked up until this point without error or fault as I developed, but doesn't now.

Comment: did you try to add the base class as I specified?