# VTSO Code doesn't compile on new laptop with Office2021/VS2022

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin, visual-studio-2022

I wrote an Outlook plug-in to help me manage the spam I receive through my mail server.

It was written for Outlook 2016 using Visual Studio 2019. My old laptop took a nosedive and crashed, refusing to power on afterward.

On the new laptop, I've upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 and Outlook 2021.

Now I'm getting a weird compiler error.

```
Error   CS0115  'AddIn.CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()': no suitable method found to override
```

Here's the referenced code:

```
    protected override IRibbonExtensibility CreateRibbonExtensibilityObject()
    {
        return new ContextMenus();
    }
```

The Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime is version  10.0.0.0.

I'm wondering if there's something I forgot to install, perhaps?

Comment: Make sure that you selected Office development item in the Visual Studio installer.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135737/error-in-once-functioning-c-sharp-project-no-suitable-method-found-to-override

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I tried that first and it didn't work for me.

Comment: Does ThisAddIn class in ThisAddIn.Designer.cs file derive from Microsoft.Office.Tools.AddInBase? If yes, can you browse to that class's definition? It should be in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\xxxx\Professional\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v4.0\Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll

Answer (score 0):

To understand whether you have got everything required for Office add-ins development with VS2022 you can try creating a new add-in project. If it does work correctly then you have got everything set up on your side. Now you can compare the newly created add-in project with a migrated one to find what is wrong with your migrated solution.

Anyway, you may find similar threads over the internet:

- [Microsoft add-in code build error --ThisAddIn.RequestComAddInAutomationService()': no suitable method found to override.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3be9847b-aec5-4e8f-ba2c-2e0c226f21e7/microsoft-addin-code-build-error-thisaddinrequestcomaddinautomationservice-no-suitable?forum=vsto)
- [Error in once functioning C# project - no suitable method found to override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32135737/error-in-once-functioning-c-sharp-project-no-suitable-method-found-to-override)

Comment: I just verified the SharePoint/Office Development tools are installed.

Comment: Does a newly created add-in work correctly? Have you tried comparing source files?

Comment: While the "Microsoft add-in code builder" link didn't give me any specifics. :( The solution given in the second link didn't work for me.

Comment: Did you try creating a new add-in project in VS2022? Does a newly created add-in work correctly? Have you tried comparing source files?